# Android - Can't understand code

Tags: android, android-layout

Can someone please try and explain this code for me, I don't really understand any of it and nowhere on the web seems to explain it. I've brought a copy of 'Android Development for Dummies' and it hasn't really helped me.

```
private TextView txtMineCount;
private TextView txtTimer;
txtMineCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MineCount);
txtTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Timer);

// set font style for timer and mine count to LCD style
Typeface lcdFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
    "fonts/lcd2mono.ttf");
txtMineCount.setTypeface(lcdFont);
txtTimer.setTypeface(lcdFont);
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: What is your question? Which part of it are you unclear about?

Comment: You probably need a basic Java book, really. What in particular don't you get?

Comment: I think I get the other lines, but no idea about this one 

Typeface lcdFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
    "fonts/lcd2mono.ttf");

I also don't really understand why I would be setting txtMineCount to another textView(defined in layout Xml). I would have thought i could just import the .ttf straight to the textview in the xml...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private TextView txtMineCount;
private TextView txtTimer;
```

This declares two local variables that can hold references to a [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).  At first they do not point to anything...so you have to assign them.

```
txtMineCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MineCount);
txtTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Timer);
```

Here we assign the two variables.  We call a method of the framework to do a lookup among the text-based widgets that have been created by an ID.  Importantly we're not creating these widgets here.  We are just finding the already-allocated object instances which correspond to some ID constants we use to name them.

It's not necessarily "safe" to assume these lookups succeed in the general case, because [View.findViewById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) can return `null`.  But the person who wrote this code is assuming that there have indeed been TextView objects created elsewhere in the code which have those particular IDs.

*(If they're wrong about that, then trying to set the typeface on `txtMineCount` or `txtTimer` will just cause an exception...)*

```
// set font style for timer and mine count to LCD style
Typeface lcdFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
    "fonts/lcd2mono.ttf");
```

Android has some default fonts that ship with the system.  But this program wants to make use of a [TrueType Font File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType) which has been embedded in the font subdirectory of the application's assets (basically a bunch of files that travel along inside your application bundle).  This creates a Typeface object suitable for applying to a TextView out of that file.

```
txtMineCount.setTypeface(lcdFont);
txtTimer.setTypeface(lcdFont);
```

This simply sets the typeface used by the two TextViews to the font from above.

---

Note that you can get an equivalent effect without the intermediate variables.  This code should do the same thing as what you posted:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.MineCount)).setTypeface(
    Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/lcd2mono.ttf"));

((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Timer)).setTypeface(
    Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/lcd2mono.ttf"));
```

But it's harder to read this way, and by not saving intermediate results in variables you can end up computing that intermediate result multiple times.  For instance, the `Typeface.createFromAsset` code is run twice with the same parameters when you write it this way.

Comment: @kcoppock My programs are full of difficult questions, so sometimes answering simple ones is a pleasant break!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your question is:

1. You've defined a couple of views in your .xml layout: txtMineCount and txtTimer.
2. You're using findViewById() to retrieve the Textview instances at runtime.
3. You're setting the "typeface" property in both views at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like a Minesweeper clone. What it's doing is creating an instance of 'TextView' (probably something for dislpaying text in a certain font (lcd thing in this case). Or did you need to know EXACTLY what each line of code does?